# Hide element after previewing picture

Tags: javascript, html, preview

Actually I'm trying to make a form to add pictures to a gallery. The thing is, the button to add picture is wider than the preview photo so when we add the picture, we have the button in the background. I precise that I'm new in Javascript.

I've tried different ways with JS but none of them are working. If someone can tell me what did I do wrong or what I can do, it will be super great !

First here is the code for the preview :

```
imageInput.onchange = (evt) => {
  const [file] = imageInput.files;
  if (file) {
    preview.src = URL.createObjectURL(file);
  }
  if (file != null) {
    preview.style.display = "block";
  }
};

const displayPreview = document.getElementById("hide");

if (file != null) {
  displayPreview.style.display = "none";
}

   <div id="upload">
       <img id="preview" src="#" alt="Votre photo" />
       <img
          id="img-img"
          src="assets/icons/img-vector.svg"
          alt="Image d'image"
       />
   <div id="hide">
       <label class="file-upload">
           <input accept="image/*" type="file" id="imageInput" />
           + Ajouter photo
       </label>
   </div>
       <p>jpg, png : 4mo max</p>
   </div>
```

Comment: getElementById should be document.getElementById. same for getElementsByClassName. These are methods of document object

Comment: Ok so first thank you, I feel so dumb for not having seen this after so many time ! 
I've change it but unfortunately it still doesn't work (with both of the two trials) so I think I've made another mistake in this

Comment: Please post your latest code. Exactly where you are hiding div.

Comment: Ok so I've editing the post to show an example with one of the two solution I've tried

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to move the line which hides displayPreview block inside the event handler. By keeping it outside like that it would not work.

you need to do something like this below.

```
const displayPreview = document.getElementById("hide");

imageInput.onchange = (evt) => {
  const [file] = imageInput.files;
  if (file) {
    preview.src = URL.createObjectURL(file);

  }
  if (file != null) {
        displayPreview.style.display = "none";
    preview.style.display = "block";        
  }
};
```

I hope this help.

Comment: Thank you !! It works now. And of course it was super helpful, moreover for someone who discover JS !